# remove usernames from twitter data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have fetched some data from Twitter using python. now I want to pre process it. how can I remove usernames if the tweet has username between two words and there is no space among them? I want to keep the words and only delete the username

for eg.
text file:
hello @rahulcan you help me?
yes @tanyatell me?

output i want:
hello can you help me?
yes tell me?

Comment: Example input and output please.

Comment: Add your data, your code , and some examples for clarification please!

Comment: ive added an example

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you store all valid usernames? I.e., how do you know that `rahulcan` is not the username? And what do you want to do, if `rahul` and `rahulcan` are both valid usernames?

Answer (score 15):

```
import re
Tweet = "Hello@username"
Tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','',Tweet)
```

This code will remove the @username and Hello will not be removed.

Comment: Would you please improve your answer by stating what your code does?

Comment: what if tweet= @usernamehello
i want "hello" and delete the username

Comment: Do you perform web scraping to get the tweets? In that case I think we can separate it. But in this case I done have even the slightest clue.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, @NegiBabu. Any idea of how to remove emojis (I have a set of tweets that are non-english.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
Tweet = "Hello@username"
Tweet = re.sub('@[\w]+','',Tweet)
```

Building on @NegiBabu's solution, Twitter only allows alphanumeric handles and so [\w] works as a better regex for this task. For e.g. with my proposed regex you wouldn't allow for @app#le to be matched.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post. I'll do it ASAP.